# How to "dropdown" a select when click on somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

This is the thing I have:

A normal select with a few options...

And the thing is, I do need to click in some other div and when I click on that one, I want the select list to show up as they were clicked normally and then allow the user to choose from the select options

I have some code already

```
<div onclick="set_select()"></div>

<select class='form-control' id='opts'>
<option selected disabled></option>
<option>Contacto</option>
<option>Entrevista</option>
<option>Prensa</option>
<option>Conferencias</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function set_select(){
    var select = document.getElementById('opts');
    return select.active = true;
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with plain html/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need some plugin to replace your standard select field with divs and then use your function to trigger that divs. One is selectmenu: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#product-selection
There is a lot more of them available: https://www.google.pl/search?q=js+select+replacement&gws_rd=cr&ei=wN5ZV8SjMIGLsgGP_IboDQ

Answer (score 0):

This is "sort" of possible but not trivial and you will need to possibly do some management of the effect as I do here in the "change" event for the select.  Not perfect but perhaps this can give you a start.

Note you MIGHT just want to use the "focus" on the select or, set the visible size as I do here, set the select size on the change to 0 with `event.target.size = 0;` and so forth.

Revised the markup a bit to allow the click handler:

```
<div id="clicker">clicker</div>

<select class='form-control' id='opts'>
  <option selected disabled></option>
  <option>Contacto</option>
  <option>Entrevista</option>
  <option>Prensa</option>
  <option>Conferencias</option>
</select>
```

Here is the script, as I said, not perfect but you can decide how you handle the change/click events.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var id = "clicker";
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  var select = document.getElementById("opts");

  div.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log('clicker div');
    select.size = select.options.length;
    select.focus();
  };
  select.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log('opt clicked');
  };
  select.onchange = function(event) {
    console.log('opt change');
    var index = event.target.selectedIndex;
    console.log(index);
    event.target.size = index + 2;
  };
}
```

Here is a fiddle you can use to get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/mL0b7ubr/

Note that if you wish to use the "default" size for the select you can detect that like so:

```
 if (event.target.type == "select-one") {
   event.target.size = 1;
 } else {
   event.target.size = 4;
 }
```

Here is a fiddle with that change and a bit cleaner on the event attachment: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/mL0b7ubr/1/